# Good Sites that are describing about MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

i started the learning MVVM pattern. So could anybody help me to list Some  Good Sites that are describing about MVVM Pattern. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) by Josh Smith is what made MVVM clear for me.

Make sure you grab a copy of the source and look through that as well.

Comment: And some additional thoughts: http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2010/03/mvvm-josh-smiths-way.html

Answer (score 3):

These two articles are both good introductions to MVVM:

http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/5-minute-overview-of-mvvm-in-silverlight/
http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv)´s a good video where Jason Dollinger builds a small WPF application based on MVVM. I found it very useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's one from MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) about using MVVM in WPF. WPF is similar to Silverlight, so it should apply to what you're trying to do with minimal changes.

Comment: Ah, damn, beat to the punch by just a few seconds. :)

Answer (score 2):

CodeProject: [A Practical Quick-start Tutorial on MVVM in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMQuickTutorial.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I like [this demo](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/01/silverlight-4-s-new-command-support.aspx) from Jeff Procise. His focus when he was writing it was on commanding, but it's a good illustration of MVVM as well. Small, but it gets the layering right, and will help you start thinking about how your layers communicate and work together.

In any case, code is 100x as useful as reading. Once you've read a few articles you've read them all, and your time is better spent looking at lots of small applications to see how they do it.